# Is there any significance to a weapon's weight?

Tags: nier-replicant-1.22474487139

I am currently in the first part of NieR: Replicant for the PS4, and I have obtained a number of one-handed swords. Each sword has its own unique stats, story, length, and weight.

As far as weight goes, there are various stats ranging from very light to heavy. I have seen slight differences in attack range while wielding longer weapons, yet I have not seen any differences when using weapons of different weights. I would have expected this to affect combo speed in battle, or movement speed while traveling the overworld, but this does not seem to the case as far as I can tell.

What is the significance to a weapon's weight, if any at all?

Comment: As somebody who doesn't play Nier is the version numbers part of the game title, or should this be tagged [nier-replicant]

Comment: @PausePause That long number is apart of the official title for the global release of the PS4 Remaster. The original release in Japan was known as Nier Replicant, so I added the numbers to be clear of which version I'm playing

Comment: @PausePause A [meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15800/124566) has been opened to discuss the tag name

Comment: @Wrigglenite please see meta post. This game is a remaster of [tag:nier]. As such it should have both tags, as people subbed to [tag:nier] will be well-positioned to answer it.

Comment: @OrangeDog If the games are identical, there is no need to have two different tags. If the games are not identical, only one game should be tagged. This is nothing new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually is significance, though not much. A lighter weapon will swing/strike faster than a heavier weapon within the same weapon class (1H, 2H, and spears). Might be worth mentioning that in the first part of the game, you will only have access to the one-handed swords.

Naturally, spears and one-handed swords will be faster than two-handed swords. You can also augment your attack speed (and more or less cancel out the effect of weapon weight) by equipping Physical Strength+ words wherever possible.

From a [GameSpot forum post](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps3/960449-nier/answers/262415-does-the-weapon-weight-matter):

> Heavier weapons strike more slowly
> but this can easily be mitigated by equipping +physical strength words to your martial arts, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: I trust the user with a Nier profile picture